# Set Mac Firmware Password from Linux

Tags: mac, firmware-password

I would like to set a firmware password on my MacBook Pro, but I only run Linux on it. I know I could download a macOS installer and use that to set the firmware password without installing macOS, but it would be a lot easier simply to set the password from Linux.

Is it possible to set the Mac firmware password from Linux? If so, how?

Comment: Have you already tried [booting into macOS recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204455) to use the firmware password tool available there?

Comment: @Nic I wiped that a long time ago.

Comment: But internet recovery should still work even after wiping that partition. What model year of MacBook Pro is this?

Comment: @Nic Mid-2012 (MacBookPro9,2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I'm not aware of any software for Linux that allows you to change the EFI firmware password on your Mac.

If you have [a recent Mac that supports internet recovery](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/383985/18101) you can reboot straight into [internet recovery mode](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201314), even if the boot disk has been formatted or overwritten. Once you've booted into a recovery environment, you should be able to use the firmware password tool.

If you have an earlier Mac, then your best bet is to find another working Mac and [create a bootable installer](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201372) to get into recovery mode without needing to overwrite your Linux installation.

Comment: Your Internet recovery suggestion worked, so I didn't have to create any install media or use another Mac (which made things a lot easier). Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Billy awesome. Glad I was able to help.

Comment: /usr/sbin/firmwarepasswd is the command line tool on macOS to set firmware password. Maybe tracing or disassembling this can help make a similar tool for Linux.