# Install MacOS (Snow Leopard) on a clean hard drive, from windows pc, from iso or whatever else

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, iso

Problem:
A friend have a MacOS computer. The hard disk inside started ticking (probably stuck heads). Hard disk was unusable.

He bought an empty hard disk but when he replaced it, it was giving a folder with a question mark icon (missing OS I suppose).

He brought me the empty hard disk asking me to reinstall OS on it. I never used Apple products.

I usually do this kind of stuff for windows and I prepare a bootable usb drive with the Windows OS on it. Plug the usb in the computer and install windows.

How to install MacOS on a clean & virgin hard drive so he can put the hard disk back on the Macbook and use it?

tl;dr: I need from Windows to install from an ISO or whatever, the Snow Leopard OS on a clean and new Hard disk, and put it back on a mac computer with the OS on it so it can start.

EDIT IT IS AN iMac 27'' from 2009 and it was mounting Snow Leopard 10.6

Comment: The best answer may be different depending on *exactly* which Mac it is. See if you can identify it from [Ultimate Mac Lookup](https://everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/) which has many different criteria you can use for identification.

Comment: @Tetsujin It's  iMac 27'' from 2009 and it was mounting Snow Leopard 10.6. Added this detail to question too.

Comment: Well there is no Internet Recovery for that age Mac: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/383985/which-macs-support-macos-internet-recovery . Usually you need a Mac to download and create a bootable installer. Though I have heard there are ways to do this on a PC...

Comment: @SteveChambers Ok, and how does a bootable installer works? On window I manage to start it from bios/boot menù. How does it works on a mac? Also, any Mac works or I need a mac with the same version as the receiving Mac where I will install? Or even better, how to do that from pc?

Thank you

Comment: Archive.org appears to have [Snow Leopard DVD images](https://archive.org/search.php?query=os%20x%20snow%20leopard&and[]=mediatype%3A%22software%22) available for download/torrenting.

Comment: Create a bootable installer on a Mac with at least a newer OS than you are installing.(there are utilities and instructions everywhere) on an 8GB thumb drive. Put it in the target Mac. Hold OPTION while booting, select the thumb drive to boot from and off you go.

Comment: @SteveChambers Ok I'll try that. The only option i have it's that I run mac on a VM and create the bootable usb from there